# Proper way to handle multiple await inside async

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an async function(controller) with multiple await inside it. For example i can have something like this:

```
exports.check_in = async (req, res, next) => {
try {   
    const place= await Place.findOne({_id: req.params.placeId});
    // MY SECOND DEPENDS ON THE RESULT OF THE FIRST ONE
    const area=  await Area.findOne(_id: place.areaId);
    const client = await Client.findOne({_id: req.body.clientId});

    // BUSINESS LOGIC HERE

    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
}
```

So my doubts are:

1. How to handle the case of the second await that depends on the first, because if the first returns [] or null, it will break for place.areaId
2. Second, if I have multiple controllers, that need to query Place, Area, Client, is it a solution to create functions for each one and call them inside the main one. What is the best method to do it?
3. If I need to write on the database the 3 independent documents, how can I be sure that all 3 are executed? I don't want one to fail, or if it fails I want to be sure to roll-back the other. Something like this

   ```
   // new client data, new area data, new place data
   await client.save();
   await area.save();
   await place.save();
   ```

Comment: Well i think you can use `&&` operator to check the data before calling the function

Comment: 1 - what should happen if first result is wrong? Should it respond with 404 or what? Clarify your requirements and proceed from them. This isn't really specific to async/await since it already results in sync-like control flow. These are the basics of programming, use conditional branching with if/else, etc. 2 - it depends. 3 - use error handling, what you're describing is a transaction, transaction support isn't great in Mongo(ose) https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html (the question doesn't even mention that you use it), rely on native implementation or do rollbacks yourself.